# Accessing HttpSession in session scoped Bean - Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-bean

I have a session scoped Bean and want to get access to the session.

I tried this:

```
    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    public WebClient oauthClient(HttpSession session) {

        ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(1024 * 1000)).build();

        return WebClient.builder()
                .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
                .filter(authHeader((String) session.getAttribute("access_token")))
                .build();
    }
```

but

```
session.getAttribute("access_token")
```

returns null.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an Problem in my Controller. This Code works fine.